# Trouble understanding limit of a sequence of complex numbers, James Brown

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I am reading Complex Variables and Applications 8th ed by James Brown and Churchill. 
On Pg $183$ Example $2$, it says

Let $z_n=-2+\iota\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}\;\; n\in N$

Using, $\lim_{n\to \infty} z_n =\lim_{n\to \infty} (x_n+\iota y_n) = \lim_{n\to \infty}x_n 
 + \iota \lim_{n\to \infty} y_n$

We get $\lim_{n\to \infty} z_n = \lim_{n\to \infty} -2 +\iota \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2} = -2 $

But the book further says that,

If we use polar coordinates, then

$r_n = |z_n|$ and $\theta_n = Arg(z_n)$ where $Arg(z_n)$ denotes the principal argument ($-\pi<\theta<\pi$), we find that,

$\lim_{n\to \infty} r_n = \lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt{(4+ \frac1{n^4})} = 2$

but that

$\lim_{n\to \infty}\theta_{2n}= \pi$ ---($1$) and

$\lim_{n\to \infty} \theta_{2n-1}=-\pi$ ---($2$)

Evidently, $\theta_n$ limit does not exists.

First of all , I want to know why the author is trying to use polar coordinates?

Secondly, I don't understand how he got $1$ and $2$?

Because $\theta_n = \arctan(\frac{\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}}{-2})\to \arctan(0) = 0$

Also is it true that
if $z_n = r_n e^{\iota \theta_n}$ and $z=re^{\iota \theta}$

then $z_n \to z$ $\iff$ $r_n \to r$ and $\theta_n \to \theta$ -- ($3$)

Is $3$ true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it is certainly true that $z_n \to -2$ as you have observed. What the book is trying to say is that the principal logarithm of $z_n$ does not tend to principal logarithm of $-2$. The principal logarithm  is defined using the principal argument which is always assumed to be a number in $(-\pi, \pi]$. For a point like $-2+it$ with $t$ positive and close to $0$ the argument is less than and close to $\pi$. On the other hand, for a point like $-2-it$ with $t$ positive and close to $0$ the argument is gretater than and close to $-\pi$. Hence the limit of $arg(z)$ as $z \to -2$ does not exist.